# Upgrade server running Ubuntu 8.04 w/plesk to Ubuntu 9.04 w/plesk

Tags: ubuntu

The Ubuntu upgrade process is pretty straightforward. However I've never upgraded a server running Ubuntu 8.04 w/ Plesk 9.2 to Ubuntu 9.04 w/ Plesk 9.2.

I was going to follow the usual Ubuntu upgrade process, but is there any extra consideration I should take since the server is running Plesk 9.2?

Anybody with experience on this one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

A minimal search shows: [yes, this could be a problem](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=82039) - but it's fairly likely that a Plesk reinstall would fix that